# SQLPLUS execute a forloop to insert table

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

```
BEGIN
    FOR v_LoopCounter IN 1..1000000 LOOP
        INSERT INTO LOOPTBL (id , first_name, last_name, current_date) VALUES (v_LoopCounter,'this_first_name','this_last_name',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
END LOOP;
END;
```

I execute the above statement in sqlplus , however seems it doesn't execute .

let's have a look on the following screen

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need a slash `/` to terminate that anonymous PL/SQL block:

```
BEGIN
  FOR v_LoopCounter IN 1..1000000 LOOP
    INSERT INTO LOOPTBL (id , first_name, last_name, current_date) 
      VALUES 
    (v_LoopCounter,'this_first_name','this_last_name',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
  END LOOP;
END;
/              --> this
```

Comment: @mytabi: To clarify this: This has nothing to do with PL/SQL. It is the tool SQL\*Plus that requires this in order to determine where the block ends. SQL\*Plus is a very old tool and it seems they had problems to get the parser working for PL/SQL blocks so they came up with the slash for this and now that's the way it (still) is.

Comment: Though it would be better to rewrite this with `forall` especially for 1M iterations